# (Java) Creating permutations of an array-list using for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, permutation

I have looked through a ton of threads and haven't been able to find the solution that I'm looking for.

I have an arraylist and I want to make a for loop that will generate its permutations (abc, cba, acb, etc) and store them individually in an arraylist or string array. Almost every solution I have seen involves creating a public class. But I need this loop to work exclusively inside of a public class.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please paste your code into the question as text. And what do you mean when you say "Almost every solution I have seen involves creating a public class"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement this yourself (*), you can just use [Collections2.permutations(list)](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#permutations-java.util.Collection-), from Guava (an excellent library).

(*) unless you are doing this for an assignment, in which case you're really only shooting yourself in the foot by letting others do it for you.